# Disable X11 window

Tags: ssh, x11, wine

I'm using `wine` (WineHQ) on a Ubuntu server to run a Windows program that pops up a window (just for status update, nothing clickable). In Wine, that is done by `X11` forwarding.

I'd like to disable this window by not showing it when I `ssh` to the server. I tried to `ssh` without `-Y` so disabling the X forwarding, but `wine` throws an error:

```
01b5:err:user:load_desktop_driver failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winex11.drv"
01b5:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
01b5:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow The explorer process failed to start.
```

Is there a way I could trick the system and let it know I'm creating an X11 window, but actually not displaying it?

Comment: I later tried to se the env. variable `DISPLAY` to `:0.0`. When I `ssh` with `-Y` this value is `:11.0`, and empty without `-Y`. I think I bypassed the display but it also made the program run more slowly. I'll try what @filipe-brandenburger said.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Xvfb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml), the *virtual framebuffer X server*, for this purpose.

This is an X server that emulates a dumb framebuffer in memory, so it does not require any display hardware or physical input devices.

Some Linux distributions (like Ubuntu) ship an [`xvfb-run`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xvfb-run.1.html) wrapper, which will start an Xvfb server, set the `DISPLAY` appropriately to use it while running the passed command-line and finally tear down the Xvfb server once the command is finished.

On Ubuntu, you can install Xvfb and xvfb-run with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

And then run your application with:

```
$ xvfb-run wine /path/to/wine/application
```

Which should work just fine on an `ssh` session without `-Y` for X11 forwarding.